# I don't understand how symlinks in plugin work

Tags: plugin-development

I'm not sure if it's a wordpress or nginx problem

I'm making a plugin, but the plugin directory is a symlink. I think it's ok since the plugin is detected, can be activated, and even some parts are working (like a menu), but on a page where it launches a script at a chortcode, it must get a style.css file and it cannot with an error `404 not found` in the console :

so my symlink is here :

- `/path/to/wp-content/plugins/symlink_plugin_directory/`

and my directory is elsewhere, with its files :

- `/another/path/to/plugin_directory/`

  - `index.php`
  - `style.css`

the probleme has something to do with the symlink, because if I create a real directory in `/path/to/wp-content/plugins/real_directory/style.css` with a copy of the style.css, it works

I call the `style.css` file with : `wp_enqueue_style('my_style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));`

so if instead I use : `wp_enqueue_style('my_style', plugins_url('real_directory/style.css', dirname(__FILE__)))`, it works

And the path that is not working and should works (in my understanding), is :

- `https://my_site/wp-content/plugins/symlink_directory/style.css`

compared to the one that works :

- `https://my_site/wp-content/plugins/real_directory/style.css`

then what is wrong ?

### what i tried ?

I was thinking maybe a GET method doesn't works with symlink in nginx, but I enabled it with `disable_symlinks off;` like it says here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157022/make-nginx-follow-symlinks, but it doesn't resolve the problem (I tried to add it in both `http{}` context and `location ~ \.php${}` context)

also I checked that symlink files and directory had the read and execution permissions, according to this SO conversation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624358/nginx-not-following-symlinks, and I hope I gave them the good user ownership (my nginx and wordpress programs runs in separate docker, I think a get it right because symlink and reallink have the same permissions and users)

and on the same conversation, there was the idea to add `autoindex on;`, which I did, without luck

finally, I also tried to change the variable `$document_root` to `$realpath_root` in nginx php-fpm configuration, as explained here : https://joshtronic.com/2019/07/29/symlinks-with-nginx-and-php-fpm/, but no much success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a really dumb error of mine :

I forgot to gives to Nginx-Container the volume which contains the hardlink ! so, in Nginx container, the hardlink pointed to by the symlink didn't existed indeed